# Execution failed for task ':tools_Download'. Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128

Tags: git, gradle

I've setup the project on a new company computer and getting following error while building the project with specific build command. i.e. in below:

```
C:\git\xxxx\Build>gradlew build_XXX
Verifying: Tools, downloading if necessary
:tools_Download
Downloading: Tools
:tools_Download FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tools_Download'.
> Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.656 secs
```

But it looks working ok when i use only build command i.e. in below:

```
C:\git\xxx\Build>gradlew build
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE
:error_check

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I am struggling since two days to get rid of this issue, googled a lot and tried many suggestions i.e. re-generated ssh key, I thought it might be network security issue since I am working on a company computer over company's network, so added network proxies in gradle.properties file and placed that file in C:\Users\MMMMMMMM\.gradle and setting environment variable i.e. in below: but no luck so far.

```
GRADLE_USER_HOME --> C:\Users\MMMMMMMM\.gradle
HOME             --> C:\Users\MMMMMMMM
JAVA_HOME        --> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161
```

This is a C project and I am using:

```
Gradle 4.6
Windows 7 64-bit
Git version 2.16.2.windows.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: `tools_Download` seems a custom task, can you share (or check) what this task is doing ?

Comment: @ToYonos: its a huge project and build.gradle doesn't have specific info, it contains following: 

apply from: "gradle/AAAAAAAA.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/BBBBBBBB.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/CCCCCCCC.gradle"
...
..
.

where AAAAAAAA.gradle have 250 lines of code. Unfortunately i cannot share everything and it'll not help as well.

Comment: @xiaomi: how do you mean :) ?

I did as following, but haven't got much info... 

C:\git\xxxx\Build>gradlew help --task tools_Download
:help
Detailed task information for tools_Download

Path
     :tools_Download

Type
     Exec (org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec)

Description
     -

Group
     -
:error_check

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: I mean that `tools_Download` is a custom task, and it should be into root your .gradle file (i think). Can you search for this task on your code ?

Comment: so basically, you can't share any gradle information and we should be able to help you with a custom task of yours. It's gonna be hard

Comment: @ToYonos: I thought it’s kind of a common/known issue but sharing all the snippets doesn't make any sense; it’ll be lot of irrelevant code. But I completely agree with you.
So far it looks Network proxy issues, for now I manually copied folder from colleague those are not being downloading via tools_Download. I'll update here more when i know more.

Comment: Issue resolved now after lot of investigation. ARTIFACTS_REPO in Build/gradle/constants.gradle was pointing out to a repository and one .POM file was missing in that repository. i.e. ARTIFACTS_REPO = 'http://abc.xyz.net/xxxx'. But thank you very much for your comments @ToYonos and Xiaomi :)